# How to get all the value from textbox in search button?

Tags: javascript, html, search, textbox, dynamic-arrays

I have this HTML Code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CarInfoStyle.css">
    </head>
    <script src="CarInfoJavascript.js"></script>
    <body>
    <div class="searchfilter">
    <div class="searchwrapper">
            <select class="selectClass" id="minYear">
                 <option value="minYear">Select Year</option>
                 <option value="(All)">ALL</option>
                 <option value="2015">2015</option>
                 <option value="2014">2014</option>
                 <option value="2013">2013</option>
                 <option value="2012">2012</option>
                 <option value="2011">2011</option>
                 <option value="2010">2010</option>
                 <option value="2009">2009</option>
                 <option value="2008">2008</option>
                 <option value="2007">2007</option>
                 <option value="2006">2006</option>
                 <option value="2005">2005</option>
                 <option value="2004">2004</option>
                 <option value="2003">2003</option>
                 <option value="2002">2002</option>
                 <option value="2001">2001</option>
                 <option value="2000">2000</option>
                 <option value="1999">1999</option>
                 <option value="1998">1998</option>
                 <option value="1997">1997</option>
                 <option value="1996">1996</option>
                 <option value="1995">1995</option>
                 <option value="1994">1994</option>
                 <option value="1993">1993</option>
                 <option value="1992">1992</option>
                 <option value="1991">1991</option>
                 <option value="1990">1990</option>
                 <option value="1989">1989</option>
            </select>
                to
            <select class="selectClass" id="maxYear">
                 <option value="maxYear">Select Year</option>
                 <option value="(All)">ALL</option>
                 <option value="2015">2015</option>
                 <option value="2014">2014</option>
                 <option value="2013">2013</option>
                 <option value="2012">2012</option>
                 <option value="2011">2011</option>
                 <option value="2010">2010</option>
                 <option value="2009">2009</option>
                 <option value="2008">2008</option>
                 <option value="2007">2007</option>
                 <option value="2006">2006</option>
                 <option value="2005">2005</option>
                 <option value="2004">2004</option>
                 <option value="2003">2003</option>
                 <option value="2002">2002</option>
                 <option value="2001">2001</option>
                 <option value="2000">2000</option>
                 <option value="1999">1999</option>
                 <option value="1998">1998</option>
                 <option value="1997">1997</option>
                 <option value="1996">1996</option>
                 <option value="1995">1995</option>
                 <option value="1994">1994</option>
                 <option value="1993">1993</option>
                 <option value="1992">1992</option>
                 <option value="1991">1991</option>
                 <option value="1990">1990</option>
                 <option value="1989">1989</option>
            </select>   


            <select id="make" onchange="DropdownOption()">
                <option value="" selected disabled>Make</option>
                <option value="alfa romeo">ALFA ROMEO</option>
                <option value="audi">AUDI</option>
                <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
                <option value="daihatsu">DAIHATSU</option>
                <option value="ford">FORD</option>
                <option value="honda">HONDA</option>
                <option value="lexus">LEXUS</option>
                <option value="mazda">MAZDA</option>
                <option value="mercedes-benz">MERCEDES-BENZ</option>
                <option value="mini">MINI</option>
                <option value="mitsubishi">MITSUBISHI</option>
                <option value="nissan">NISSAN</option>
                <option value="subaru">SUBARU</option>
                <option value="suzuki">SUZUKI</option>
                <option value="toyota" name="toyota">TOYOTA</option>
                <option value="volkswagen">VOLKSWAGEN</option>
            </select>

            <select id="Model" disabled>
                <option value="Model" name="model" selected disabled>Model</option>
            </select>

            <input type="text" size="20" placeholder="Search" id="searchtext">
            <input type="button" name="searchbutton" value="Search" onclick="createTable()">
            <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="ResetAll()">
    </div>

</div>

<div class="CSSTableGenerator" >
    <table id="MyTable" cellspacing='0'>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this JS Code:

```
    var carData = [{
    "ConditionNotes": {},
    "Photos": {},
    "RealChassisNo": "BJ5W-315859",
    "Age": 0,
    "Miles": 0,
    "ImprovementCost": 0,
    "AirBagType": 0,
    "M3": 0,
    "Category": 0,
    "IsMiles": false,
    "IsInnerCargo": false,
    "IsPreSold": false,
    "IsNoNZ": false,
    "InnerCargoNote": null,
    "DateStock": "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/",
    "IsSold": false,
    "PriceSales": 0,
    "PriceConfirmation": 0,
    "PriceExport": 0,
    "PriceATSales": 0,
    "ScaledMargin": 0,
    "PriceDynamic": 0,
    "FobFees": 332000.0000,
    "OFSFees": 1440.0000,
    "CIFFees": 0,
    "FreightRate": 0,
    "PriceBase": 0,
    "MarketTerm": null,
    "IsIncludeOPC": false,
    "CustomerTerm": null,
    "LandedCost": 0,
    "NZNote": null,
    "NZStructuralNote": null,
    "NZStructuralCost": 0,
    "IDIBCInfo": null,
    "TransportStatus": null,
    "DateDeparture": "\/Date(1281801600000)\/",
    "DateArrive": "\/Date(1283788800000)\/",
    "ShipName": "Saracen Star(KB)",
    "TypeOfSale": "",
    "BuyTripCustomer": "",
    "IsSplitCurrency": false,
    "Currency": "JPY",
    "CountryID": 75,
    "IsFollowing": false,
    "FrieghtAndInsuranceTerm": null,
    "FrieghtAndInsuranceFees": 0,
    "PriceBaseForATNZ": 0,
    "IDVehicle": "232960",
    "Price": 0,
    "MaskChassisNo": null,
    "Make": "MAZDA",
    "Model": "FAMILIA",
    "Year": 2002,
    "Month": 0,
    "Type": null,
    "Location": null,
    "Grade": "S-F",
    "Transmission": null,
    "KMS": 0,
    "EngineDisplacement": null,
    "Fuel": null,
    "Doors": null,
    "ConditionGrade": null,
    "Color": null,
    "IsPowerSteering": false,
    "IsPowerWindow": false,
    "IsAirConditioned": false,
    "InteriorColor": null,
    "InteriorType": null,
    "HasSunRoof": false,
    "Length": 0,
    "Width": 0,
    "Height": 0,
    "WheelStyle": 0,
    "HasSpareKey": false,
    "SalesNote": null,
    "IsSale": false,
    "IsNewArrival": false,
    "IsReserved": false,
    "IsThailandStocks": false,
    "IsLeftHandDrive": false,
    "DateInspected": "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/",
    "ExteriorVideo": null,
    "InteriorVideo": null,
    "IsSingaporeStocks": false,
    "IsUKStocks": false,
    "IsOriginalLHD": false,
    "CustomerPort": null,
    "Airbag": 0,
    "IsNonSmoker": false,
    "Tonnage": 0,
    "InteriorGrade": null,
    "DateConfirm": "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
    }, {
    "ConditionNotes": {},
    "Photos": {},
    "RealChassisNo": "ZZE127-0006450",
    "Age": 0,
    "Miles": 0,
    "ImprovementCost": 0,
    "AirBagType": 0,
    "M3": 0,
    "Category": 0,
    "IsMiles": false,
    "IsInnerCargo": false,
    "IsPreSold": false,
    "IsNoNZ": false,
    "InnerCargoNote": null,
    "DateStock": "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/",
    "IsSold": false,
    "PriceSales": 0,
    "PriceConfirmation": 0,
    "PriceExport": 0,
    "PriceATSales": 0,
    "ScaledMargin": 0,
    "PriceDynamic": 0,
    "FobFees": 347000.0000,
    "OFSFees": 1440.0000,
    "CIFFees": 0,
    "FreightRate": 0,
    "PriceBase": 0,
    "MarketTerm": null,
    "IsIncludeOPC": false,
    "CustomerTerm": null,
    "LandedCost": 0,
    "NZNote": null,
    "NZStructuralNote": null,
    "NZStructuralCost": 0,
    "IDIBCInfo": null,
    "TransportStatus": null,
    "DateDeparture": "\/Date(1284480000000)\/",
    "DateArrive": "\/Date(1286208000000)\/",
    "ShipName": "Spring Sky(KB)",
    "TypeOfSale": "",
    "BuyTripCustomer": "",
    "IsSplitCurrency": false,
    "Currency": "JPY",
    "CountryID": 75,
    "IsFollowing": false,
    "FrieghtAndInsuranceTerm": null,
    "FrieghtAndInsuranceFees": 0,
    "PriceBaseForATNZ": 0,
    "IDVehicle": "233407",
    "Price": 0,
    "MaskChassisNo": null,
    "Make": "TOYOTA",
    "Model": "WILL",
    "Year": 2002,
    "Month": 0,
    "Type": null,
    "Location": null,
    "Grade": "Vs",
    "Transmission": null,
    "KMS": 0,
    "EngineDisplacement": null,
    "Fuel": null,
    "Doors": null,
    "ConditionGrade": null,
    "Color": null,
    "IsPowerSteering": false,
    "IsPowerWindow": false,
    "IsAirConditioned": false,
    "InteriorColor": null,
    "InteriorType": null,
    "HasSunRoof": false,
    "Length": 0,
    "Width": 0,
    "Height": 0,
    "WheelStyle": 0,
    "HasSpareKey": false,
    "SalesNote": null,
    "IsSale": false,
    "IsNewArrival": false,
    "IsReserved": false,
    "IsThailandStocks": false,
    "IsLeftHandDrive": false,
    "DateInspected": "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/",
    "ExteriorVideo": null,
    "InteriorVideo": null,
    "IsSingaporeStocks": false,
    "IsUKStocks": false,
    "IsOriginalLHD": false,
    "CustomerPort": null,
    "Airbag": 0,
    "IsNonSmoker": false,
    "Tonnage": 0,
    "InteriorGrade": null,
    "DateConfirm": "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
    }]; 

    createTable = function() {

    if(document.getElementById("searchtext").value == "" || document.getElementById("searchtext").value == null){
        var table = document.getElementById("MyTable");
        table.innerHTML = "";
        var header = table.createTHead();
        var row = header.insertRow(0);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
        cell1.innerHTML = "Chassis";
        cell2.innerHTML = "Year";
        cell3.innerHTML = "Make";
        cell4.innerHTML = "Model";
        cell5.innerHTML = "Model Grade";
        cell6.innerHTML = "Ship Name";

        var makevalue = document.getElementById("make").value;
        var modelvalue = document.getElementById("Model").value;
        var minYearvalue = parseInt(document.getElementById("minYear").value);
        var maxYearvalue = parseInt(document.getElementById("maxYear").value);

        var table = document.getElementById("MyTable");

        for (var i in carData) {

          console.log(carData[i]['Make'].toLowerCase(),makevalue.toLowerCase(), carData[i].Model,modelvalue,carData[i].Year,minYearvalue,maxYearvalue);
          if (carData[i]['Make'].toLowerCase() == makevalue.toLowerCase() && carData[i].Model == modelvalue && carData[i].Year >= minYearvalue && carData[i].Year <= maxYearvalue) {
            console.log('adding');
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
            var chassisCell = row.insertCell(0);
            var yearCell = row.insertCell(1);
            var makeCell = row.insertCell(2);
            var modelCell = row.insertCell(3);
            var modelGradeCell = row.insertCell(4);
            var shipNameCell = row.insertCell(5);

            chassisCell.innerHTML = carData[i].RealChassisNo;
            yearCell.innerHTML = carData[i].Year;
            makeCell.innerHTML = carData[i].Make;
            modelCell.innerHTML = carData[i].Model;
            modelGradeCell.innerHTML = carData[i].Grade;
            shipNameCell.innerHTML = carData[i].ShipName;
          }
        }
    }
    else{
        Search();
    }
    };
    function Search(){

     var table = document.getElementById("MyTable");
     table.innerHTML = "";
     var header = table.createTHead();
     var row = header.insertRow(0);
     var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
     var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
     var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
     var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
     var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
     var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
     cell1.innerHTML = "Chassis";
     cell2.innerHTML = "Year";
     cell3.innerHTML = "Make";
     cell4.innerHTML = "Model";
     cell5.innerHTML = "Model Grade";
     cell6.innerHTML = "Ship Name";
     var textsearch = document.getElementById("searchtext").value.toUpperCase();

     for(var counter = 0; counter < 757; counter++){

          if(carData[counter].RealChassisNo.lastIndexOf(textsearch) != -1 ||     carData[counter].Make.lastIndexOf(textsearch) != -1 ||     carData[counter].Model.lastIndexOf(textsearch) != -1 ){
       var table = document.getElementById("MyTable");
       var rowCount = table.rows.length;
       var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
       var chassisCell = row.insertCell(0);
       var yearCell = row.insertCell(1);
       var makeCell = row.insertCell(2);
       var modelCell = row.insertCell(3);
       var modelGradeCell = row.insertCell(4);
       var shipNameCell = row.insertCell(5);

       chassisCell.innerHTML = carData[counter].RealChassisNo;
       yearCell.innerHTML = carData[counter].Year;
       makeCell.innerHTML = carData[counter].Make;
       modelCell.innerHTML = carData[counter].Model;
       modelGradeCell.innerHTML = carData[counter].Grade;
       shipNameCell.innerHTML = carData[counter].ShipName;
      }

     }
    }

    DropdownOption = function(carData) {
      document.getElementById("Model").disabled = false;
      var model = document.getElementById("Model");
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      var make = document.getElementById("make").value;
      model.innerHTML = "";

      option.text = "Model";
      model.add(option);
      option.innerHTML = "Model";

      if (make == "alfa romeo") {
        document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
        var choice = document.createElement('option');
        choice.innerHTML = "156";
        model.appendChild(choice);
      } else if (make == "audi") {
        document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
        var audi = ["A4", "A3", "TT"];

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          var choices1 = document.createElement('option');
          choices1.value = audi[i];
          choices1.innerHTML = audi[i];
          model.appendChild(choices1);
        }
      } else if (make == "bmw") {
        document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
        var bmw = ["116I", "118I", "120i", "120I", "1 SERIES", "320I", "323I", "MINI", "MINICOOPER", "MINI COOPER S", "X1", "X3"];

        for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      var choices2 = document.createElement('option');
      choices2.value = bmw[i];
      choices2.innerHTML = bmw[i];
      model.appendChild(choices2);
        }
      } else if (make == "daihatsu") {
        document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
        var choice3 = document.createElement('option');
        choice3.innerHTML = "BeGo";
        model.appendChild(choice3);
      } else if (make == "ford") {
        document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
        var ford = ["Escape", "Focus", "Kuga"];

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          var choices4 = document.createElement('option');
          choices4.value = ford[i];
          choices4.innerHTML = ford[i];
          model.appendChild(choices4);
        }
      } else if (make == "honda") {
        document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
        var honda = ["ACCORD", "AIR WAVE", "CIVIC", "CIVICFERIO", "CR-V", "EDIX", "ELYSION", "FIT", "HR-V", "INSPIRE", "ODYSSEY", "STEPWAGON", "STREAM"];

        for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
          var choices5 = document.createElement('option');
          choices5.value = honda[i];
          choices5.innerHTML = honda[i];
          model.appendChild(choices5);
        }
      } else if (make == "lexus") {
        document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
        var lexus = ["IS250", "IS350"];

        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          var choices6 = document.createElement('option');
          choices6.value = lexus[i];
          choices6.innerHTML = lexus[i];
          model.appendChild(choices6);
        }
      } else if (make == "mazda") {
        document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
        var mazda = ["AXELA", "ATENZA", "BONGO", "DEMIGO", "FAMILIA", "MPV", "PREMACY", "VERISA"];

        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
          var choices7 = document.createElement('option');
          choices7.value = mazda[i];
          choices7.innerHTML = mazda[i];
          model.appendChild(choices7);
        }
      } else if (make == "mercedes-benz") {
        document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
        var mercedesbenz = ["A170", "A200", "C230", "C200 KOMPRESSOR"];

        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          var choices8 = document.createElement('option');
          choices8.value = mercedesbenz[i];
          choices8.innerHTML = mercedesbenz[i];
          model.appendChild(choices8);
        }
      } else if (make == "mini") {
        document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
        var mini = ["COOPER", "MINI ONE"];

        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          var choices9 = document.createElement('option');
          choices9.value = mini[i];
          choices9.innerHTML = mini[i];
          model.appendChild(choices9);
        }
      } else if (make == "mitsubishi") {
        document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
        var mitsubishi = ["COLT", "COLT PlUS", "DELICA", "GALANT", "GRANDIS", "LANCER", "OUTLANDER", "PAJERO", "PAJERO MINI"];

        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
          var choices10 = document.createElement('option');
          choices10.value = mitsubishi[i];
          choices10.innerHTML = mitsubishi[i];
          model.appendChild(choices10);
        }
      } else if (make == "nissan") {
        document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
        var nissan = ["BLUEBIRD SYLPHY", "CARAVAN", "CUBE", "DUALIS", "FAIRLADY", "FUGA", "JUKE", "LAFESTA", "MARCH", "MURANO", "NOTE", "NV200", "NV350 CARAVAN", "PRESAGE", "STAGEA", "SKYLINE", "TEANA", "TIIDA", "TIIDA LATIO", "VANETTE", "WINGROAD", "X-TRAIL"];

        for (i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
          var choices11 = document.createElement('option');
          choices11.value = nissan[i];
          choices11.innerHTML = nissan[i];
          model.appendChild(choices11);
        }
      } else if (make == "subaru") {
        document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
        var subaru = ["EXIGA", "FORESTER", "IMPREZA", "LEGACY", "LEGACY TOURING WAGON", "TRAVIQ", "OUTBACK"];

        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
          var choices12 = document.createElement('option');
          choices12.value = subaru[i];
          choices12.innerHTML = subaru[i];
          model.appendChild(choices12);
        }
      } else if (make == "suzuki") {
        document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
        var suzuki = ["ESCUDO", "FORESTER", "JIMNY", "SWIFT", "SX-4"];

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          var choices13 = document.createElement('option');
          choices13.value = suzuki[i];
          choices13.innerHTML = suzuki[i];
          model.appendChild(choices13);
        }
      } else if (make == "toyota") {
        document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
        var toyota = ["ALLEX", "ALLION", "ALTEZZA", "AURIS", "AVENSIS", "BB", "BLADE", "CALDINA", "CAMRY", "COROLLA AXIO", "COROLLA FIELDER", "COROLLA RUNX", "ESTIMA", "HIACE", "HILUX SURF", "IPSUM", "IST", "ISIS", "IQ", "LANDCRUISER PRADO", "MARK X", "MARK ZIO", "RACTIS", "RAV4", "REGIUS ACE", "RUSH", "SUCCEED", "TOWNACE", "VANGUARD", "VITZ", "WILL", "WISH"];

        for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
          var choices14 = document.createElement('option');
          choices14.value = toyota[i];
          choices14.innerHTML = toyota[i];
          model.appendChild(choices14);
        }
      } else if (make == "volkswagen") {
        document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
        var volkswagen = ["GOLF", "GOLF VARIANT", "PASSAT VARIANT", "TIGUAN", "TOUAREG"];

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          var choices15 = document.createElement('option');
          choices15.value = volkswagen[i];
          choices15.innerHTML = volkswagen[i];
          model.appendChild(choices15);
        }
      }
    };
```

The Search textbox is okay when you type Example: "mazda" only in the textbox then click search button it will display the given data. But if I type Ex: "toyota will" and click search button it will not display the given data, instead it will only display the THead cell[1-6]. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code further until [no code can be removed while still running into the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Create Object from JSON String</h2>

Name: <input type="text"  id="text" size="20">
Value: <input type="text" id="get" size="20">
<input type="button" id="search" value="Seach" placeholder="Search" onclick="Search()">
</table>
<script>
function Search(){
 var val = document.getElementById("text").value;
 
 document.getElementById("get").value = "" + val;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>                     this code seems to work and gets all the value in the first textbox, and display it in another textbox, I don't know why what's the problem with code the above.

Comment: You should probably [edit] to add that in, or just work out what the difference is until you can get a fairly small sample that does have the problem.

Comment: You should not be using innerHTML for an option. And you have SO MUCH repeated code.

Comment: what method should I use for the option tag?